# C# data type on var

Tags: .net

var data type take more time to compile (i.e convert in to IL )
so why we need var datatype as well as compliler know the particular dattype at runtime(i.e Compile time only) so when am using this may program may have chance to reduce the performance.

any one explain this concept with example and compile time duration please.....

Comment: "var data type take more time to compile" -- I don't think it does...

Comment: AFAIK `var` is resolved at compile time. So you may only encounter a performance degrade while compiling, if any - not while executing.

Comment: `var` is resolved at compile time. It might be interesting to compare a large program with `var` against one that uses specific type declarations; however, I predict the difference will be tiny compared to, say, the time spent reading source files from disk.

Comment: @Andreas - That's implementation-specific obviously, but the compiler needs to resolve the type either way at compile time, even for explicitly declared types (because C# is a strongly typed language, even if the type is explicitly declared on the left side the compiler needs to resolve the type on the right side of the assignment anyway to make sure that everything is a-ok) so I doubt that there's *any* performance hit at all.

Comment: @DrJokepu - I could even imagine that it is faster in some cases, but it is suspicious. Think of something like `IInterface i = new IfaceImpl()`. For that the Compiler has to check whether `IfaceImpl` implements  `IInterface`. With `var` the inferred type of `i` would rather be `IfaceImpl`, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 5):

`var` isn't a data type - it's just a way of telling the compiler to infer the type itself. If doesn't make any difference at execution time. The compiled code will be exactly the same.

`var` was primarily introduced as part of *anonymous types* where you can't explicitly declare a variable of the appropriate type, as it has no name. This feature in turn is primarily used in LINQ, where you often have ad-hoc projections.

There are other benefits of `var` however in terms of reducing duplication - for example, if you're already specifying the type exactly in the assignment expression, there's little point in having it on the left-hand side:

```
// Simple
var namesMap = new Dictionary<string, Person>();

// Duplication and more to read
Dictionary<string, Person> namesMap = new Dictionary<string, Person>();
```

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of the `var` keyword is to let you declare variables of anonymous types. For instance, I can rewrite a `var` declaration for plain types:

```
// This:
var i = 6;
// ...is the same as this:
int i = 6;
```

However I can't do the same thing for compiler-generated types:

```
// This isn't valid C#:
var a = new { i = 6, s = "hello" };
(what goes here?) a = new { i = 6, s = "hello" };
```